# I'm trying to add and subtract from a label with two functions but it only lets me subtract not add

Tags: swift, xcode

This code only allows me to do the function subpressed, but every time I remove subpressed, the pluspressed works.

```
@IBAction func subpressed(_ sender: Any) {
    ttmar -= 1
    ttma.text = "\(ttmar)"
    let ttDefault=UserDefaults.standard
    ttDefault.setValue(ttmar, forKey: "ttmar")
    ttDefault.synchronize()
}


@IBAction func pluspressed(_ sender: Any) {
    ttmar += 1
    ttma.text = "\(ttmar)"
    let ttDefault=UserDefaults.standard
    ttDefault.setValue(ttmar, forKey: "ttmar")
    ttDefault.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: Double-check the connections from the storyboard. Most probably, both buttons are connected to the same action.

Answer (score 4):

you must sure to connected your object to code 
for check this you have 2 ways :

1 : click on your table and go to (show the connections inspector ) 
[image: show the connection inspector]

2: right click on your object and then you can find your func ( if it connected)

[image: right click on object]